# Bigqueryreservation gives an 400 Invalid Argument Error when creating an assignment

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I am getting this error when trying to implement BigQuery Slot Reservation from google cloud in python as explained here: https://cloud.google.com/python/docs/reference/bigqueryreservation/latest/google.cloud.bigquery_reservation_v1.services.reservation_service.ReservationServiceClient

I have also tried to run the code as described in this blog:
https://medium.com/google-cloud/optimize-bigquery-costs-with-flex-slots-e06ec5e4aa90

As far as I figured out I use the correct methods and arguments and the error appears when making the request.
When I run

```
  assign_config = Assignment(job_type='QUERY',
                         assignee='projects/{}'.format(user_project))
  assign = res_api.create_assignment(parent=reservation_id,
                                 assignment=assign_config)
```

I get this error

> *InactiveRpcError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
> /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/google/api_core/grpc_helpers.py
> in error_remapped_callable(*args, **kwargs)
> 66         try:
> ---> 67             return callable*(*args, **kwargs)
> 68         except grpc.RpcError as exc:
>
> 6 frames /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/grpc/_channel.py in
> **call**(self, request, timeout, metadata, credentials, wait_for_ready, compression)
> 945                                       wait_for_ready, compression)
> --> 946         return _end_unary_response_blocking(state, call, False, None)
> 947
>
> /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/grpc/_channel.py in
> _end_unary_response_blocking(state, call, with_call, deadline)
> 848     else:
> --> 849         raise _InactiveRpcError(state)
> 850
>
> _InactiveRpcError: <_InactiveRpcError of RPC that terminated with:    status = StatusCode.INVALID_ARGUMENT    details = "Request contains an
> invalid argument."    debug_error_string =
> "{"created":"@1650884667.228899135","description":"Error received from
> peer
> ipv4:142.250.141.95:443","file":"src/core/lib/surface/call.cc","file_line":903,"grpc_message":"Request
> contains an invalid argument.","grpc_status":3}"
>
> > 
>
> The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
>
> InvalidArgument                           Traceback (most recent call
> last)  in ()
> 5   )
> 6
> ----> 7 assign = client.create_assignment(parent=res_id, assignment=assign_config)
>
> /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/google/cloud/bigquery_reservation_v1/services/reservation_service/client.py
> in create_assignment(self, request, parent, assignment, retry,
> timeout, metadata)    1871     1872         # Send the request.
> -> 1873         response = rpc(request, retry=retry, timeout=timeout, metadata=metadata,)    1874     1875         # Done; return the
> response.
>
> /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/google/api_core/gapic_v1/method.py
> in **call**(self, *args, **kwargs)
> 143             kwargs["metadata"] = metadata
> 144
> --> 145         return wrapped_func(*args, **kwargs)
> 146
> 147
>
> /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/google/api_core/grpc_helpers.py
> in error_remapped_callable(*args, **kwargs)
> 67             return callable_(*args, **kwargs)
> 68         except grpc.RpcError as exc:
> ---> 69             six.raise_from(exceptions.from_grpc_error(exc), exc)
> 70
> 71     return error_remapped_callable
>
> /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/six.py in raise_from(value,
> from_value)
>
> InvalidArgument: 400 Request contains an invalid argument.

My full code:

```
!pip install protobuf==3.19.0
!pip install google-api-python-client==2.45.0
!pip install google-cloud-bigquery-reservation
from google.colab import auth
auth.authenticate_user()

project_id = 'my-id'
region = 'EU'
parent_arg = "projects/{}/locations/{}".format(project_id, 
                                               region)

!gcloud config set project {project_id}

from google.cloud import bigquery_reservation_v1
from google.cloud.bigquery_reservation_v1 import *
from google.cloud import bigquery
client = bigquery_reservation_v1.ReservationServiceClient()

def purchase_commitment(slots=500):
  commit_config = CapacityCommitment(plan='FLEX', slot_count=slots)
  commit = client.create_capacity_commitment(parent=parent_arg,
                                              capacity_commitment=commit_config)
  print(commit)
  return commit.name

def create_reservation(reservation_name, slots=500):
  res_config = Reservation(slot_capacity=slots, ignore_idle_slots=False)
  res = client.create_reservation(parent=parent_arg, 
                                   reservation_id=reservation_name,
                                   reservation=res_config)  
  print(res)
  return res.name

def create_assignment(reservation_id, user_project):
  assign_config = bigquery_reservation_v1.Assignment(
    #job_type=bigquery_reservation_v1.types.Assignment.JobType(2), 
    job_type="QUERY", 
    assignee=f"projects/{project_id}"
  )

  assign = client.create_assignment(parent=res_id, assignment=assign_config)
  print(assign)
  return assign.name

reservation_name = 'sample-reservation'

slots = 500
commit_id = purchase_commitment(slots)
res_id = create_reservation(reservation_name, slots)
assign_id = create_assignment(res_id, project_id)
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the code above for making the assignment, I used the code below:

```
assignment_config = Assignment(job_type='QUERY', assignee='projects/{}'.format(project_id))
  assignment = client.create_assignment(CreateAssignmentRequest(
      parent=res_id,
      assignment=assignment_config,
  ))
```

Also instead of using the project_id in number format, I used the full name of the project. This